# Setup a internet domain on windows server, on EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns

sorry for this newbie question, as a Developer I never setup a web domain dns on a windows server. I already buy my .com domain, i will get an instance on amazon ec2. How I setup the dns on windows server 2008, to get traffic to my domain? Any tutorial? I have looked, but all i find is setup a local domain. Any tip for Amazon EC2?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Assign an Elastic IP address to your server
2. Use your ISP's/Domain registrar's DNS tools to point your domain name at this ip address. The exact steps here will vary depending on who controls your domains DNS settings.
3. In iis, right-click on your site and choose edit bindings. Set your domain name as the host name (eg www.mydomain.com)

Answer (score 2):

For most domain name hosts, they'll have some sort of way for you to link the domain name to a particular ip address or other domain name, both of which you can get from Amazon AWS. You can link an elastic ip that is associated with your instance and it'll work like a charm.